# Water vapor pressure in oxygen bubble

Tags: pressure, evaporation, bubbles

Suppose we have a source of O$_2$ bubble formation in water at specific nucleation sites, how can we estimate the water vapor pressure inside the O$_2$ bubbles?

I know that:

(1): $p_\mathrm{O_2}+p_\mathrm{H_2O} = p_\mathrm{tot}$

(2): $c_\mathrm{O_2} = K_\mathrm{O_2}\cdot p_\mathrm{O_2}$ (Henry's law)

where $c_\mathrm{O_2}$ is the concentration of $O_2$ in the liquid phase, and $p_x$ are partial pressures. How can I get $p_\mathrm{H_2O}$ probably as a function of $O_2$ gas pressure?

Comment: The partial pressure of the water inside the oxygen bubble will be the vapor pressure of water at its temperature.  See the Antoine equation on Wikipedia for more details.

Comment: the young-laplace equation will furnish the mechanical pressure present inside the bubble due to surface tension effects.

Comment: @DavidWhite so you think the vapor pressure of water will be independent of the oxygen pressure that builds up?

Comment: @nielsnielsen indeed the surface tension will play a role here. can we get the oxygen partial pressure as a function of surface tension and O2 partial pressure?

Comment: for a static bubble the young-laplace equation will furnish the interior pressure. equate this to the sum of the partial pressures. Include water vapor pressure and assume saturated conditions.

Comment: @Guiste, the vapor pressure of water is a function of temperature, but it is not a function of the other gases that the water vapor is mixed with.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_equation

Comment: @DavidWhite That is in the ideal-gas case only? Because water evaporates more easily in vacuum than under air.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I used the Kelvin equation (which is the Young-Laplace equation for the case of evaporation), but found that if the bubble is not of nano-meter size, there is no modification of the partial pressure inside the bubble compared to a plane O2-water interface. I am however wondering that there is an effect of O2 pressure on the water concentration even at a planar O2-water interface, but I do not know how to estimate that

Comment: sorry- I don't either.

Comment: @Guiste, your assertion is overly broad.  In addition, calling something the "ideal case" because it doesn't agree with your idea of how things should be is not helpful.  I've had actual experience with this type of problem, based on 21 years of industrial chemical engineering experience, so I didn't just make up my answer.

Comment: @DavidWhite Was there a misunderstanding here? I meant that an ideal gas partial pressure (I mean the ideal gas as defined in thermodynamics) does not change with external pressure (or added background gas), but a real gas partial pressure will change? I did not say in any way that you made up your answer or wanted to say that, I was just trying to understand what you are saying.